# conditional column join in sql lite

Tags: sqlite, join, conditional-statements, left-join, sql-null

Like on following webpage I want to do a conditional column join in sql lite

https://dev.to/gschro/conditional-column-join-in-sql-5g03

however it seems that this is not possible?

So this is my join:

```
left join query_506556 as rdi_data on rdi_data.time = y.datetime_weather AND case when a.monitor_id is null then 1 when a.monitor_id = rdi_data.device_id then 1 else 0
```

I want to join on 2 things, datetime from my y table (which is ok) and monitor_id from my a table which is not always represent. And I want to be sure that when it is not represent, the data from the rdi_data is also coppied

error code:

```
Error running query: near "order": syntax error
```

Is this kind of join possible in sql lite?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
left join query_506556 as rdi_data 
    on  rdi_data.time = y.datetime_weather 
    and (a.monitor_id is null or a.monitor_id = rdi_data.device_id)
```

Or, if you want to match on `null` values as well (but it does not look like that's what you asked for), then use `is`, which is the null-safe operator in SQLite:

```
left join query_506556 as rdi_data 
    on  rdi_data.time = y.datetime_weather 
    and a.monitor_id is rdi_data.device_id
```